# Create an iPhone app with more than one "screen"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am relatively new to Objective-C / iPhone programming, and have only created single view applications thusfar.  I am interested in creating an app soon than will have a "wireframe" in a sense that allows me navigate the various views of my app using buttons.  So I guess my questions are:

1. What do I need to do to make an app that has more than one view
2. How to I link them with UIActions in buttons to navigate the various screens (ex a back button to go to a previous screen)

and I may have more as I go, but this is a start.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe he covers storyboards, Navigation ViewControllers and Tab ViewControllers in one of the videos.

Comment: just realized his course covers a lesson specifically on multiple MVC's and segues... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one really had a clear helpful answer, I will share my own conclusion.  Xcode 4 offers a very intuitive and interactive way to create multiple MVCs and segue between them even providing the interface to travel between views.  I found out how to use this feature from Paul Haggarty's iOS course on iTunes U.  I highly recommend it.

Joey

Answer (score -1):

You'd can use a combination of, multiple `UIViewController` and or `UINavigationController`'s. Utilizing methods such as `presentModalViewController:animated:` and `pushViewController:`.